# Display qgrid within the ipywidget tab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, qgrid

I'm trying to use qgrid to visualize dataframes together with some widgets. I have some issues displaying a grid inside a tab, if it is not active at the load.

```
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import qgrid

out1 = widgets.Output()
out2 = widgets.Output()
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = 10))
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = 10))

with out1:
    display(qgrid.show_grid(data1))

with out2:
    display(qgrid.show_grid(data1))

tab = widgets.Tab(children = [out1, out2])
tab.set_title(0, 'First')
tab.set_title(1, 'Second')
display(tab)
```

The code above produce working version for the first tab

[image]

But the second one is empty

[image]

More surprising is the fact that my attempt to "inspect" this in Chrome fixes my second tab, but hides output from the first.

Any suggestions?